# DateTime format into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to insert into a SQL Server database using a C# application.

In C# I am using `datetime.now` to get the current datetime:

```
order.PendingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

This gives me `25/07/2014 11:30:17`.

In the SQL Server table the datatype is `datetime`. Which holds the data as `2014-07-23 14:54:01.607` for example.

However running the value `25/07/2014 11:30:17` using a normal insert script it inserts into the SQL Server table fine but displays in the table as `2014-07-25 11:30:17`. (This is ok)

However when I use `SqlConnection`

```
using (con)
{
   con.Open();
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
       cmd.Connection = con;
       cmd.CommandText = @sql;
       cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
}
```

It fails, it says

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

I think this is because Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server uses a different datetime format to each other.

How do I fix this?

Current Code:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Order ([LedgerNumber], [OrderNumber], [OrderDate], [PendingDateTime], [EmailAddress]) VALUES (1, '" + rec.OrderNumber + "', CONVERT(datetime, '" + rec.OrderDate + "', 120), CONVERT(datetime, '" + rec.PendingDateTime + "', 120), '" + rec.EmailAddress + "')";
try
    {
       SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrderContext"].ConnectionString);
    using (con2)
        {con2.Open();
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
         {
         cmd.Connection = con2;
         cmd.CommandText = @sql;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rec.PendingDateTime", DateTime.Now);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rec.OrderDate", rec.OrderDate);
         cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         }
```

Comment: Use sql-parameters instead of string-concatenation.

Comment: What is `@sql` definition?

Comment: Even better, if you're always going to pass in `DateTime.Now`, just let the database handle that for you with either a default for the column or using `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use sql-parameters instead of string-concatenation. It prevents you from such issues and - more important - from sql-injection:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Order ([LedgerNumber], [OrderNumber], [OrderDate], [PendingDateTime], [EmailAddress]) 
               VALUES (1, @OrderNumber, @OrderDate, @PendingDateTime, @EmailAddress)";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrderContext"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", rec.OrderNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", rec.OrderDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PendingDateTime", rec.PendingDateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", rec.EmailAddress);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

You: "*if I wasn't using datetime.now and get a datetime from a value entered by user. Say '24/07/2014 10:30' how do I use the AddWithValue to achieve this?*"

You have to parse the input to `DateTime` first. Therefore use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`, `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`. The `TryParse`-methods enable you to check if the input is a valid `DateTime`.

For example:

```
DateTime pendingDateTime;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(TxtPendingDateTime.Text, out pendingDateTime))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Pending-Date in the format: yourformat");
    return;
}
// here you can go on with the code above
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, if I wasn't using datetime.now and get a datetime from a value entered by user. Say '24/07/2014 10:30' how do I use the AddWithValue to achieve this?

Comment: You have to parse the input to `DateTime` first. I have edited my answer acccordingly.

Comment: Just reading on the AddwithValue to see what it does, but my current code:

Comment: @user3636272: i have edited my answer again to take your code into account. Note also that i've used `ExecuteNonQuery`. I would use `ExecuteScalar` only if you get something back, for example the new identity value. Therefore you'd need to add `;SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);` to the insert-query.

Comment: My current code is showing above. I am passing through the entity through to the method, can I still use sql paramters as i am using the entity fields to pass through the values to be used in the sql command?

Comment: That is brilliant @TimSchmelter. I just had to open the connection too with addition to your bit of code. That has worked.

Everyday is a school day, thanks for your help. I will continue to keep using sql parameters now.